# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split' error

Tags: python

## When I run this code I get the error AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Any Help would be appreciated

```
#python3.5
print("WELCOME TO THE CLEVERBUY SYSTEM!")
productArray= []
productsFile = open("products.txt","r")
print (productsFile.split(","))
login = False
while login == False:
    FName = input ("ENTER FIRST NAME - ")
    custID = input ("ENTER CUSTOMER ID - ")
    email = input ("ENTER E-MAIL - ")
    if custID in productArray:
        if "@" not in email:
            print ("incorrect e-mail")
        else:
            if "." not in email:
                print ("incorrect e-mail")
            else:
                if FName.isalpha():
                    print ("Welcome")
                    login = True
                else:
                    print("incorrect first name")
    else:
        print("customer ID not found in system")
```

Comment: You're trying to call `split` on a file object. File objects don't have such a method, which is exactly what the error is saying. If you want to read the whole file into one giant string, you can do that with `productsData = productsFile.read()`, and then `productsData.split()` is fine.

Comment: Hint: `productsFile.split(",")` won't work.

Comment: @scharette How is that a hint? That's what's in the code, and he's already got an exception pointing to exactly that expression telling him it doesn't work.

Comment: @abarnert I thought it was relevant for him to try himself before, since as you said the error is really verbose. Feel free to give him the entire answer yourself (as you already did) and miss the opportunity for him to practice using the exception returns (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

You have not read your file to return a string you have a file object.

> To read a file’s contents, call f.read(size), which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes object (in binary mode). size is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been reached, f.read() will return an empty string ('').

See [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

You just need to read it and it should work:

```
file = open("products.txt","r")
productsFile = file.read()
print (productsFile.split(","))
```

Don't forget to close your file:

```
file.close()
```

**Or better practice:**

```
with open("products.txt","r") as file:
    productsFile = file.read()
```

This will automatically close the file for you.

---

`'_io.TextIOWrapper'` is what is returned when you open a file (but have not read/written in it).  You can test this by using the interactive interpreter:

```
>>>open('file.txt', 'r')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='file.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

You can determine three things from this:

- The name of the file.
- The encoding.
- the mode that `open()` has been set in.

---

Here is a [tutorial from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) on reading files.